# How to support consuming application configurable authentication providers using spring-security-oauth2

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security-oauth2

While prototyping out an API & SDK, I've run into this question with several plausible solutions. I'm looking for help with some of the high level architecture. In short, it is guaranteed that some consuming applications of the API are going to want to configure their own authentication providers.

Options that I've been munching on:

1. Keep resource server and authorization coupled but figure out some way to delegate authentication in one of the authentication providers in my auth manager to the client application.

*This sounds promising until I realized that in the particular use case, it's actually necessary that even my providing application not know the user's credentials.*

2. Separate the resource server and make each consuming application responsible for providing an authorization server, and set those endpoints as part of the configuration when registering the consuming app with the resource provider.

*This feels like an uncomfortable inversion of what is often desired when using authorization_code grant types. It also would require any "default" authorization providers to be implemented by each consuming application.*

3. Some kind of delegating authorization server that falls back to a default if a client hasn't provided endpoints for their own authorization server.

This would probably be a good solution, but I'm not sure how to do it the "spring-security-oauth2" way or if I'd have to implement a bunch of my own stuff.

4. Create a default auth server, and optionally allow consuming applications to point to whichever auth server they want.

*This seems viable approach in that it offers lots of customization. My concern is, how do I enforce some kind of registry with the resource server? If the auth server is the server that approves consuming applications, but I don't want to let any consuming application implement its own auth server, just some of them. Otherwise non-trusted clients could end up approving themselves!?*

In case this influences any guidance, my resource provider will need a fully inflated OAuth2Authentication object (which contains user details and client details).

This image mostly explains what I'm talking about, except I want multiple authorization servers and want to leave it to the consuming application to decide which authorization server to point at. How could I check on the resource-server side of things that the authorization server proxying the requests is an approved authorization server?

[image: le image]

**ADDENDUM:**

I took a look at the existing implementation that's being used for this custom authentication case and I guess we're just reading a token off their session that gets set by their own login service and building their user each time off of that. This sort of customization is a problem in that we're removing customizations from the provider side of things in favor of handling that in the consuming applications. So, I'm looking for solutions so consuming apps can define their own authentication means, to the point of even providing users that the providing application doesn't persist (which leads me to think it may need to be an entire auth server).

That being said, this seems like a potentially unsustainable inverted model (IMHO, the provider should be the maintainer of users and authorization, not the consuming apps). So, I'll probably recommend a more business oriented change.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a nightmare. I should probably just go sleep on it.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I'll do the same, but consider this: is it really the whole auth server that you want to be able to allow arbitrary new instance of, or is it maybe just the authentication piece (which isn't really an OAuth2 concern anyway)? Things might get easier (assuming I understand your use case) if the resource server and token content and format were in your control.

Comment: @DaveSyer - could you give my proposed answer a look? Is this possible without throwing out everything we get from spring-security-oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have finally come up with a secure and maintainable way of solving this.

1. Let consuming applications optionally register an authentication callback with the authorization server.
2. Require incoming authorization requests from that application to the authorization server on behalf of a user to include a token, that token should be stored by the consuming application as a means of referencing whichever user is actively causing the API call.
3. When an authorization code request is received by the authorization server from an application that has registered one of these callbacks, then POST to that application's registered authentication callback and include the token that was provided by the consuming application in the request.
4. The consuming application should take the token that was POSTed to it's registered authentication callback and look up the corresponding user, and return a response containing the full user object on whose behalf the providing application should operate (or some kind of error code if the token is invalid).
5. The authorization server should then generate an authorization code and return to the callback uri submitted with the authorization code request. This means we're back on track according to step 4 in the diagram in the original question. The remaining steps can be carried out as-is.

There is a remaining question of how this might be implemented to take advantage of as much of the spring-security-oauth2 framework as possible while still achieving this extension.

Comment: "Require incoming authorization requests from that application to the authorization server on behalf of a user to include a token..." That bit looks difficult to me (since ideally you want to accept requests from a standard HTTP redirect, where all headers will be lost). If you want to chat about it we can use gitter (https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth).